# Multiple domains laravel

Tags: laravel, dns

I'm looking for directions for where to begin doing this:

I want my Laravel website to have multiple domains. More specifically I want to make this link:

```
"domain1/id" => "domain2"
"domain1/id/profile" => "domain2/profile"
"domain1/id/logo.png" => "domain2/logo.png"
```

And I want to make this as easy as possible for the domain2 owner. Server specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3
- Vagrant 2.0.3

If you need any other information I'll be here.

Comment: You can achieve this with a redirect mapping of each `id` to their corresponding domain. However, as there are actually a lot of ways to go about this (redirects at app level, at webserver level, subdomains, etc) could you provide more details on what specifically are you willing to implement?

Comment: And what about this Vagrant 2.0.3? Please don't say that you use Vagrant on live server?

Comment: My mistake the server does not have vagrant

Comment: what I'm trying to achieve is a website simmilar to a blog where the users have their fake url "domain1/id" but can connect their own domain. Each account is linked to this id. The users could share their domains as if it were their own website. Idealy they would point their domain to our ip and tell the softwere what their domain is and the softwere would make the connection automatically.